# Example of matrix with no JCF

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is a trivial example of a matrix $A$ over a field $K$ with no JCF?

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ over $\mathbb R$.